# NodeJS: ENAMETOOLONG, how long is too long?

Tags: node.js, error-handling

The https://nodejs.org/api/os.html says:

> ENAMETOOLONG  Indicates that the filename is too long.

but, how long is too long, if I am to prevent it from happening myself beforehand?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on OS you running node.

```
BTRFS   255 bytes
exFAT   255 UTF-16 characters
ext2    255 bytes
ext3    255 bytes
ext3cow 255 bytes
ext4    255 bytes
FAT32   8.3 (255 UCS-2 code units with VFAT LFNs)
NTFS    255 characters
XFS     255 bytes
```

More information here: https://serverfault.com/a/9548