# Strapi >>> Facing "ENAMETOOLONG: name too long" error

Tags: node.js, strapi

System information

- Strapi Version: 4.1.12
- Operating System: MacOS
- Database: Postgres
- Node Version: 16.15.1
- NPM Version: 8.11.0
- Yarn Version: 1.22.11

When I try to upload a file with long name then I’m getting below error:

`error: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long`

File name: **Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book here a.pdf**

Can someone help me with the root cause of this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's your file system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54742403). Your example filename *looks* exactly 255 bytes, but you have a "fancy quote" in there. It's not an apostrophe (0x27) or backtick (0x60) but three bytes, `0x2e 0x80 0x99`. The error is entirely correct: *name too long*.

[You can check this list](https://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=8064&names=-&utf8=0x), search for character `U+2019` and you'll see this sequence of bytes matches your quote character.

---

JavaScript's string functions, such as `''.substr()` work on *characters* and not *bytes*, so simply using `filename.substr(0, 255)` will not work.

The best way is to use an external package that knows how to trim UTF-8 strings without breaking special character sequences, like your multi-byte quote or emoji.

```
const truncate = require('truncate-utf8-bytes');
const { extname, basename } = require('path');

function trimFilenameToBytes(filename, maxBytes = 255) {
  // By extracting the file extension from the filename,
  // it'll trim "verylong.pdf" to "verylo.pdf" and not "verylong.p"
  const ext = extname(filename);
  const base = basename(filename, ext);
  const length = Buffer.byteLength(ext);
  const shorter = truncate(base, Math.max(0, maxBytes - length)) + ext;
  // Just in case the file extension's length is more than maxBytes.
  return truncate(shorter, maxBytes);
}

const filename = 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy \
text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has \
been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, \
when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it \
to make a type specimen book here a.pdf';

console.log(
  'This string is',
  filename.length,
  'characters and',
  Buffer.byteLength(filename, 'utf-8'),
  'bytes'
);

console.log(trimFilenameToBytes(filename));

// Will log the following, note how it's 2 bytes shorter:
// This string is 255 characters and 257 bytes
// Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy \
// text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has \
// been the industry’s standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, \
// when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it \
// to make a type specimen book here.pdf
```

Comment: Thank you @RickN for the answer, Let me check the possibility as you mentioned

Comment: In case you need it, or should anyone stumble upon this question in the future having the same problem, I've added a very basic example how to trim a filename to a certain byte length.