# ENAMETOOLONG on ng build of Angular project

Tags: angular

I'm trying to build an Angular app using `ng build` but I'm getting an error:

> An unhandled exception occurred: ENAMETOOLONG: name too long, open '/home/peter/Documents/projects/WebApp/WebApp/dist/webappv2/app-modules-company-components-company-settings-administration-settings-modals-administration-edit-modal-administration-edit-modal-component-es2015.js'
> See "/tmp/ng-KCATI4/angular-errors.log" for further details.

The path of the file is:

> WebApp/src/app/modules/company/components/company-settings/administration-settings/modals/administration-edit-modal/administration-edit-modal.component.ts

Is there a reason why `ng-build` converts it to a single long file name?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/54741533/5468463

Answer (score 0):

Using `ng build --prod` fixed the issue.